# Addition of the SUM of two independant tables

Tags: mysql

i have two tables

td_sell

```
|----------|----------------|------------------|
|  id      |   user_id      |    price         |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  1       |      2         |     10           |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  2       |      1         |      5           |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  3       |      2         |      3           |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

and td_commsion

```
|----------|----------------|------------------|
|  id      |   user_id      |    price         |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  1       |      1         |      3           |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  2       |      1         |      5           |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  3       |      2         |      3           |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

now i want a sql query like this

```
SELECT (SUM(td_sell.price) + SUM(td_comission.price)) AS his_earning
FROM td_sell, td_comission 
WHERE td_sell.user_id='1'
AND td_comission.user_id='1'
```

but its showing abnormal result

the result should be `13`, but its showing `29`

Comment: You are joining the tables incorrectly. Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html for more information on how to use joins.

Comment: btw you have typos: see td_coMMision

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(s.price) FROM td_sell s WHERE s.user_id = 1)
+
(SELECT SUM(c.price) FROM td_comission c WHERE c.user_id = 1)
```

**DEMO**: [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27dac/9)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the sum of the Cartesian join of the two tables.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(price)
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM td_sell
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM td_commission
) a
where a.user_id=1
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle:
[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/133e99/4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the sum separately on each table, before combining the results.  Here is one way:

```
select (sell + commission) as his_earning
from (select SUM(td_sell.price) as sell
      from td_sell
      where td_sell.user_id='1'
     ) s cross join
     (select SUM(td_comission.price) as commission
      from td_comission
      where td_comission.user_id='1'
     ) c
```