# Addition of Sum From different tables

Tags: mysql

I already posted it as a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171091/addition-of-the-sum-of-two-independant-tables), and I got the answer, but the answer itself has a flaw.

I have 4 different tables and each of them have two fields in common `total_share` and `idea_user_id`.

I want to get the sum of "SUM of total_share" from all the tables

Here's my query

```
SELECT SUM
        (
            ifnull(s.total_share, 0) + 
            ifnull(r.total_share, 0) + 
            ifnull(c.total_share, 0) +  
            ifnull(p.total_share, 0)
        ) as total_sum
FROM idea_submitter_percentage s
left outer join idea_revisor_percentage r on r.idea_user_id = s.idea_user_id
left outer join idea_contributor_percentage c on c.idea_user_id = s.idea_user_id
left outer join idea_comparisor_percentage p on p.idea_user_id = s.idea_user_id
WHERE s.idea_user_id = 3
```

It works fine, but there are two issues:

1. If `idea_submitter_percentage` doesn't have any tuples where `idea_user_id=3`, then it returns `null`, however if other tables have no entry it doesnt return `null`.
2. If all of the tables don't have any tuple where `idea_user_id=3`, it returns `null`, however it should return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when doing a `JOIN` you expect one "master" table that has at least one result. In your case, that is not guaranteed. The way to solve your problem is to use the `UNION` statement:

```
SELECT idea_user_id, SUM(total_share) AS total_share
FROM (

    SELECT s.idea_user_id, s.total_share
    FROM idea_submitter_percentage s
    WHERE s.idea_user_id = 3

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.idea_user_id, r.total_share
    FROM idea_revisor_percentage r
    WHERE r.idea_user_id = 3

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.idea_user_id, c.total_share
    FROM idea_contributor_percentage c
    WHERE c.idea_user_id = 3

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p.idea_user_id, p.total_share
    FROM idea_comparisor_percentage p
    WHERE p.idea_user_id = 3
) a
```

A `UNION` will happily ignore tables that don't have any results. You can see that it works at this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b048/8